# Error while installing package thats need XGBOOST

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost

I am trying to install the "MLBox" python package on anaconda (Python 3.6).
This package needs "xgboost" so I download the wheel file from this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#xgboost) and I did a pip install wheel-file. I had no issue with it. But when I use the pip install for installing "mlbox" I have this error:

```
Collecting pandas==0.20.3 (from mlbox)
Using cached pandas-0.20.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: joblib==0.11 in c:\users\amira ayadi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mlbox)
Collecting scikit-learn==0.19.0 (from mlbox)
Using cached scikit_learn-0.19.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Theano==0.9.0 in c:\users\amira ayadi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mlbox)
Collecting xgboost==0.6a2 (from mlbox)
Using cached xgboost-0.6a2.tar.gz
No files/directories in C:\Users\AMIRAA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6ytmh20a\xgboost\pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

I also tired to install xgboost with anaconda solution (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost)

But same error.

Do you have some ideas? 
I am on Windows 10

Comment: Why not install simply from pip? [`pip install xgboost`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/python-package)

Comment: @VivekKumar, because of this note : Note for windows users: this pip installation may not work on some windows environment, and it may cause unexpected errors. pip installation on windows is currently disabled for further invesigation, please install from github.